# Mysql import csv not complete by Mysql bench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I upload the csv file which has more than 5 thousand rows  table data for option import wizard by Mysql Workbench. As the result the output table only 335 rows, have no idea how to overcome the limitation.

Comment: Please show some lines that where not imported and also the create table where you try to import them. So that we can jave a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to the contents of your CSV-file - and that in turn is determined by the used program that created it in the first place ...

Check if all lines have the desired number of values per line, in combination with:

Check if escape-characters (if any) are there .. and you give them in mysql-workbench as well ...

special case for Microsoft Excel - it used to create ONE escape sequence for first occurance, 2 Escape sequences for 2nd occurance and so forth ... I had to use a php-script to import them, where I had to hand-twiddle until mysql was satisfied with the input-format

compare those successful lines with other lines in the csv - What is the difference between them?